# Ошибка: POST http://localhost:8080/submit 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: javascript, post, axios

Мне нужна Ваша помощь в поиске ошибки.

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const TOKEN = process.env.TOKEN;
const CHAT_ID = '-*************';
const URL_API = `https://api.telegram.org/bot${TOKEN}/sendMessage`;

app.post('/submit', (req, res) => {
  const { name, tel, comment } = req.body;
  const message = `<b>Заявка с сайта!</b>\n`;
  const formattedMessage = `${message}<b>Отправитель: </b> ${name}\n<b>Телефон: </b> ${tel}\n<b>Имя пользователя: </b> ${comment}`;

  axios
    .post(URL_API, {
      chat_id: CHAT_ID,
      parse_mode: 'html',
      text: formattedMessage,
    })
    .then(response => {
      res.json({ success: true, message: 'Сообщение отправлено!' });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'Произошла ошибка при отправке сообщения',
      });
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Ошибка: axios.min.js:1     POST http://localhost:8080/submit 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: Хмм, я ошибок вроде как не вижу. Единственное, что приходит на ум, что у вас токен или не правильно из `.env` файла берется, или просто сам по себе не правильный, из-за чего вы отправляете запрос например на `.../bot/token/sendMessage`, тут токен = `/token`, просто как пример привел. Т.к. ошибка 405 означает, что вы пытаетесь отправить `post` запрос, а сервер не принимает `post` запрос по указанному `URL_API`, по этому в примере выше вы будете пробовать достучаться `post` запросом по не правильному пути и сервер вернет вам 405 ошибку. (хотя не факт, может повезет и сервер примет запрос)

Comment: @ПавелЕриковstandwithRussia а если я попробую сменить token в файле .env ? может помочь, как считаете ?

Comment: Я не знаю. В коде я лично ошибок не замечаю, может слепой. По этому предполагаю, что ошибка там, чего я не вижу. А не вижу я вашего токена. Я не прошу его показывать)) Просто убедитесь, что он правильный. Что он правильно записан в `.env` файле. Попробуйте по выводить в консоль все, что вы передаете в `axios` и посмотреть все ли правильно передается.

Comment: @ПавелЕриковstandwithRussia Спасибо! Буду пробовать